# Counting possible ways for a group of objects

Tags: combinatorics

A drawing with n different objects is being coloured. For every object a painter uses one of k different colors.

a) for which values of k is sure that no matter how is the drawing coloured, at least one color will be used for at least four objects?

b) for how many different colourings of the objects in the drawing every color is used at least once?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: For (a) it’s easier to turn the problem around: given $k$ colors, what values of $n$ will guarantee that at least one color is used for at least $4$ objects?

If $k=1$, the result is guaranteed whenever $n\ge 4$. If $k=2$, $n=6$ is too small, since you might have three objects of each color, but $n\ge 7$ works: no matter how you split $7$ or more objects into two parts, one part contains at least $4$ objects. If $k=3$, $n=9$ is too small, since you could have three objects of each color, but $n\ge 10$ works: no matter how you split $10$ or more objects into three parts, one part contains at least $4$ objects. Now generalize this reasoning to find the general principle. It may help to realize that you’re using a form of the pigeonhole principle. Once you have the minimum $n$ that ‘works’ for each possible $k$, it’s not hard to turn it back around and get the maximum $k$ that ‘works’ for any given $n$.

For (b), observe that there are $k^n$ ways to color $n$ objects with $k$ colors. Now use an [inclusion-exclusion argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to subtract the colorings that don’t use all $k$ colors.